# How to test a StoreService in Angular 14 for a HTTP delete backend API service?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

How to mock out a successful call to delete api service (which wraps the Angular Http service) which returns an Observable for the successful deletes scenario?  It doesn't return void.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution - specifically the part returning an object with a 200 that suffices for the mock of the call to the api-service which returns the result of httpService.delete of Angular.

```
 describe('ItemStoreService', () => {
      let service: ItemStoreService;
      let itemApiServiceSpy: SpyObj<ItemApiService>;
      let notifyServiceSpy: SpyObj<NotifyService>;
      let anItem: Item;
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        anItem = {
          id: 1,
          name: 'testName',
        };
    
        itemApiServiceSpy = createSpyObj('ItemApiService', ['delete', 'loadActiveItems']);
        notifyServiceSpy = createSpyObj('NotifyService', ['notifyError', 'notifySuccess']);
    
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [
            { provide: ItemApiService, useValue: itemApiServiceSpy },
            { provide: NotifyService, useValue: notifyServiceSpy },
          ],
        }).compileComponents();
        service = TestBed.inject(ItemStoreService);
      });
    
      it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
      });
    
      it('delete should call notifyError on error ', () => {
        itemApiServiceSpy.delete.and.returnValue(
          throwError(() => {
            return { status: 500, message: 'testError' };
          })
        );
    
        service.delete(anItem.id);
    
        expect(itemApiServiceSpy.delete).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(anItem.id);
        expect(notifyServiceSpy.notifySuccess).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(notifyServiceSpy.notifyError).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
          'A problem was encountered while deleting Non-Production Bottle Lot ' + anItem.id
        );
      });
    
      it('delete should call notifySuccess on success ', () => {
        let loadActiveItemsSpy = spyOn(service, 'loadActiveItems');
    
        itemApiServiceSpy.delete.and.returnValue(of({ status: 200, message: 'deleted.' }));
    
        service.delete(anItem.id);
    
        expect(itemApiServiceSpy.delete).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(anItem.id);
        expect(notifyServiceSpy.notifyError).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(loadActiveItemsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(notifyServiceSpy.notifySuccess).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Non-Production Bottle Lot was deleted.');
      });
    });
```